# Accessing the method of a class (which implements an interface), which is not declared in the Interface

Tags: java, class, object, oop, interface

I am trying to play around with interfaces and classes and stumbled upon the below scenario.

I have an interface `MyInterface` with `interfaceMethod()`, which is implemented by `MyClass1` class. `MyClass1` implements the `interfaceMethod()` and also has its own public method `myClass1Method()`.

Now, when I create `myClass1Obj1` object for `MyClass1` via interface, the `myClass1Method()` is not accessible (I understand why it's not accessible). I wanted to know if there is way to access the `myClass1Method` using the `myClass1Obj1`.

One way to access the `myClass1Method()` is to create an object of `MyClass1` and access the method. I'm more curious to know if `myClass1Method()` can be accessed via `myClass1Obj1`.

Below is the code representation of above scenario.

Interface definition

```java
public interface MyInterface {
    void interfaceMethod();
}
```

Class definition

```java
public class MyClass1 implements MyInterface{

    @Override
    public void interfaceMethod(){
        System.out.println("MyClass1.interfaceMethod");
    }

    public void myClass1Method(){
        System.out.println("MyClass1.myClass1Method");
    }

    public static void main(String []args){
        MyInterface myClass1Obj1 = new MyClass1();
        myClass1Obj1.interfaceMethod();
        myClass1Obj1.myClass1Method(); // Compile time error - Cannot resolve method 'myClass1Method' in 'MyInterface'

        MyClass1 myClass1Obj2 = new MyClass1();
        myClass1Obj2.myClass1Method();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```java
if( myClass1Obj1 instanceof MyClass1 myInterfaceObj )
{
  myInterfaceObj.myClass1Method();
}
```

For those more traditionally inclined and more daring is this alternative:

```java
((MyClass1) myClass1Obj1).myClass1Method();
```

More daring, because the second does not perform any checks whether `myClass1Obj1` is really an instance of `MyClass1`, but on the other side with the code we see: what else could it be?

Of course we can have it also without casting:

```java
final var method = myClass1Obj1.getClass().getMethod( "myClass1Method" );
method.invoke( myClass1Obj1 );
```

As I am lazy, all the recommended error handling is missing here. Not to mention that your compiler and/or IDE will complain about the unhandled exceptions.

Comment: It is probably worth noting that pattern matching with `instanceof` was only introduced with Java 16 (or Java 14 as preview feature)

Comment: Jepp, and it is part of version 17 LTS, so it will remain in the language for some time. But most important is: it is nowadays Java …